# StyledComponents: Referencing another component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want my parent component's `:after` selector's properties modified whenever the child is focused. This seemed pretty easy at the get go but for some reason, I can't get it to work.
My component tree looks something like this:

**Component Tree**:

```js
<Wrapper>
 <Input type='text'/>
</Wrapper>
```

**Definitions**:

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  &:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: solid 3px black;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
`
const Input = styled.input`
border: none;
  width: 90%;
  transform-origin: center;
  display: inline-block;
  :focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  &:focus ${Wrapper}:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
`
```

I want my parent to display a `border-bottom` whenever the child is focused and the `border-bottom` to disappear whenever the child is not in focus. Any ideas as how I can achieve this? What am I missing/doing wrong?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do this only with styles . but i have a good idea.

you can save your input focus state like this :

```
  const [isFocused,setIsFocused] = useState(false);


  <Input onFocus={()=>{setIsFocused(true)}} onBlur={()=>{setIsFocused(false)}} />
```

and pass `isFocused` to your wrapper :

```
<Wrapper focused={isFocused} >
```

now you can use `isFocused` in your styles :

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
   border-bottom:${props=>props.focused&&"1px solid black"};
`;
```

Comment: I figured there was some way to use only styled components but I guess not.